# SQL aggregate rows with same id , specific value in secondary column

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, having-clause, conditional-aggregation

I'm looking to filter out rows in the database (PostgreSQL) if one of the values in the `status` column occurs. The idea is to sum the `amount` column if the unique `reference` only has a `status` equals to `1`. The query should not `SELECT` the `reference` at all if it has also a status of `2` or any other `status` for that matter. `status` refers to the state of the transaction.

Current data table:

```
reference | amount | status
   1         100       1       
   2         120       1
   2        -120       2
   3         200       1
   3        -200       2
   4         450       1
```

Result:

```
amount | status
  550      1
```

I've simplified the data example but I think it gives a good idea of what I'm looking for. 
I'm unsuccessful in selecting only `references` that only have status `1`.
I've tried sub-queries, using the `HAVING` clause and other methods without success.

Thanks

Comment: hey what is your query at this stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `not exists` to sum all rows where the status is 1 and other rows with the same reference and a non 1 status do not exist.

```
select sum(amount) from mytable t1
where status = 1
and not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.reference = t1.reference
    and t2.status <> 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
 FROM table
WHERE reference NOT IN (
 SELECT reference
 FROM table
 WHERE status<>1
)
```

The subquery SELECTs all `reference`s that must be excluded, then the main query sums everything except them

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum (amount) as amount
from (
    select sum(amount) as amount
    from t
    group by reference
    having not bool_or(status <> 1)
) s;
 amount 
--------
    550
```

Comment: I like the use of `bool_or` aggregate function :)

Comment: thanks however the query results in both answers in references that have more than one status (i.e reference 2,3 ). Resulting in aggregation of all rows. Perhaps my example is not sufficient and doesn't cover the use-cases here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `windowed functions` to count occurences of status different than 1 per each group:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM (SELECT *,COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE status<>1) OVER(PARTITION BY reference) cnt
      FROM tc) AS sub
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/EZSV96801)**